# Feeding snakes skinned rabbits

Tags: diet, snakes

I farm rabbits for pelts and meat. I’ve been wanting to get a snake but I would like to keep the pelts for my pillows and blankets. Would giving a python a skinned animal be okay or do they need that skin and hair? Is there nutrition properties they need in that?

Answer (score 1):

Feeding skinless animals is OK, in order to ensure that your snake is getting all their nutrients the rabbits should be fed a long-term healthy diet with nutrient rich foods.

Some more information can be found here:

[Is it possible to gut-load a mouse?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/is-it-possible-to-gut-load-a-mouse?rq=1)

[How do I gut load a cricket](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/how-do-i-gut-load-a-cricket)