# How can I provide supplements to an ocelot gecko who won't eat dusted crickets?

Tags: diet, feeding, lizards, geckos, crickets

Our ocelot gecko had some problem with a dusted cricket when he was very young (he vomited it for some reason) and since then he won't even look at crickets that have been dusted with calcium and vitamins. We are trying to compensate by giving him small amounts of vitamins/calcium with a little water on the tip of his nose, so that he'll lick it, a method he finds very annoying.

I have a pretty hard time looking for something I could feed to the crickets so that they contain enough calcium and vitamin D<sub>3</sub>. The only things I was able to find in my area are variants of dry calcium vitamins mixes for dusting.

Are there any alternatives I could use to make sure that my gecko will get all of the nutrients he needs? Such as a way to feed crickets naturally? I try to feed them cheese or curd but that won't solve the vitamin issue.

Or does anybody have similar experience with a gecko rejecting dusted insects, and know of some way to make them more appealing so that he'll start eating them again?

Comment: The alternative to dusting the crickets would be gut-loading. We have a main question here: [How do I gut load a cricket?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/how-do-i-gut-load-a-cricket) although I think the topic has come up in some of the other reptile feeding questions.

Comment: Gut loading has been found to be the least effective way of making a food more nutritious. As a matter of fact bearded Dragons fed only gut loaded crickets ended up thin and malnourished, while ones fed dusted crickets were healthier. The healthiest bunch, however, were the ones fed the VitaBugs crickets and worms. Are you able to order these for your geckos?

Comment: These comments should be decent answers. Why do you put your answers in comment box? Unless you don't want credit for it.

Comment: Gutloading and dusting serve different purposes - neither is intended to replace the other. Dusting is *only* vitamins and minerals, and generally those that it is hard for the reptile to get through food. Gutloading can also provide things like carbohydrates, fats, proteins, fibre, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had an Ocelot gecko before who didnt eat dusted crickets. Only way I solved this problem was to go to petsmart and buy some live crickets and some food and vitamins for them and feed it to my lizard (his name was "Allie"). It worked and had no issues then. Lizards tend to be very picky with food and that could lead them to starving themselves and trust me my little brother had a little who was so picky it died. Very sad. Anyway try to see the Exotic vets to. They might be able to give you better info.

Comment: See related [How do I gut load a cricket](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1691)